# How do you overload the caret (^) operator in python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, caret

I need to override the caret behaviour in a class, but I'm not sure which operator overload applies to it. For example:

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __caret__(self, other):
        return self.f^other.f

print A(1)^A(2)
```

This code errors with:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

How can I construct the class so that I can control the behaviour?

Comment: RTFD http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: I see you're using Python 2. You should always use `class A(object):` instead of `class A:`. Old-style classes should never be used.

Comment: Why is this? What are the disadvantages of not inheriting from object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define `A.__xor__()` or `A.__rxor__()`.

Answer (score 3):

The ^ is an xor operator.  You can overload it with the `__xor__` method.

For example

```
>>> class One:
...     def __xor__(self, other):
...             return 1 ^ other
... 
>>> o = One()
>>> o ^ 1
0
>>> o ^ 0
1
```